# listView in dialog with setState

Tags: flutter

I have a problem, if I use without dialog it's working perfect, containers destroyed, but in dialog listView's element in else branch have height, the container takes up the space it occupied when it had the content, but he is null, I try to set height 0 - not working, I try used keys, but don't know how its help me not work too, try in first put Stateful and next dialog.
How I can repair this?

[image]

```
Future<void> _showMyDialog() async {
TextEditingController editingController = TextEditingController();
return showDialog<void>(
    context: context,
    
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return Dialog(
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
          child: StatefulBuilder(builder: (context, setState) {
            return Container(
              height: 600,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    child: TextField(
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        setState(() {});
                      },
                      controller: editingController,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          labelText: "Поиск",
                          hintText: "Поиск",
                          prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius:
                                  BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(25.0)))),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    height: 420,
                    //список групп еды
                    child: ListView.builder(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0, bottom: 10),
                        itemCount: foods.length,
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        // ignore: missing_return
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          if (editingController.text.isEmpty) {
                            return Container(
                                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                    left: 10.0, right: 10.0, bottom: 10),
                                child: RaisedButton(
                                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                      borderRadius:
                                      new BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    ...
                                    }
                                    Navigator.pop(context);
                                    _controllers.clear();
                                    setState(() {});
                                  },
                                  child: Text(
                                    '${foods[index].name}',
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                  ),
                                ));
                          } else if (foods[index].name.toLowerCase().contains(
                              editingController.text.toLowerCase())) {
                            return Container(
                                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                    left: 10.0, right: 10.0, bottom: 10),
                                child: RaisedButton(
                                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                      borderRadius:
                                          new BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    ...
                                  },
                                  child: Text(
                                    '${foods[index].name}',
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                  ),
                                ));
                          } else {
                            Container();
                          }
                        }),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
                    width: 320.0,
                    child: RaisedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                      },
                      child: Text(
                        "Назад",
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            );
          }));


    });
  }

  void getAllFood() {
    for (int i = 0; i < foodList.length; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < foodList[i].foods.length; j++) {
        foods.add(foodList[i].foods[j]);
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **StatefulBuilder** to use **setState** inside **Dialog** and update **Widgets** only inside of it.

You can wrap your **Dialog** with **StatefulBuilder** as below:

```
showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (context) {
    String contentText = "Content of Dialog";
    return StatefulBuilder(
      builder: (context, setState) {
        return Dialog(
          title: Text("Title of Dialog"),
          content: Text(contentText),
          actions: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(
              onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
              child: Text("Cancel"),
            ),
            FlatButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  contentText = "Changed Content of Dialog";
                });
              },
              child: Text("Change"),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  },
);
```

Comment: does not work, my list still makes empty lines between the selected elements and this only in the dialog